# Find the cubic bezier control points from end points and tangents

Tags: bezier-curve

If i have 2 end points and two unit vectors as tangents at the two end points is it possible to find the cubic bezier curve control points that make the curve ? Is there one solution or many solutions ?

Visual of what i am trying to find:
[image]

Comment: You need two more constraints, such as the curvature at each end, or two points on the curve.

Comment: How would you define the curvature of the two points exactly ? What does that mean ?

Comment: Formally, curvature is the rate of change of the tangent angle with respect to arc length; less formally, the reciprocal of the radius of the best-fitting circle at that point.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many solutions. At the start of the curve, the given point and unit vector define a line. You can place the curve’s second control point anywhere along this line. The same reasoning applies at the end of the curve.